# Bot Framework - Sign out a user completely in Teams

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

We have built a Teams bot using Bot Framework (version 4.0). The bot is working fine.

What we want to accomplish is provide a logout/login functionality in the bot. To logout, the user would type in a special command (say "log me out") and we would log the user out. Now when the user interacts with the bot next time, we want the user to manually sign-in by showing them the OAuth dialog.

This is the code we have written for signing out the user and it does not throw any errors:

```
var userTokenClient = innerDc.Context.TurnState.Get<UserTokenClient>();
await userTokenClient.SignOutUserAsync(innerDc.Context.Activity.From.Id, _connectionName, innerDc.Context.Activity.ChannelId, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("You have been signed out."), cancellationToken);
return await innerDc.CancelAllDialogsAsync(cancellationToken);
```

However when the user sends the next message, Bot framework somehow automatically signs them in (I am guessing that the login session is terminated on the server but the tokens are not removed from the local cache).

I am wondering if there is another way to completely sign out the user and remove the token cache so that user is presented with an OAuth login dialog on the next conversation.

Someone suggested to remove Teams cache folder locally but that is also not working.

We even tried the following code and getting the same result:

```
await MyOAuthPrompt.SignOutUserAsync(innerDc.Context);
```

Comment: Please refer the samples below for logout functionality


https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/553be780ccedbfcf6167d2e608e48ef043831930/samples/app-sso/csharp


https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/553be780ccedbfcf6167d2e608e48ef043831930/samples/bot-conversation-sso-quickstart/csharp_dotnetcore/BotConversationSsoQuickstart

Comment: @vikram-MSFT: Thank you for the comment. I looked at the code [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/553be780ccedbfcf6167d2e608e48ef043831930/samples/bot-conversation-sso-quickstart/csharp_dotnetcore/BotConversationSsoQuickstart/Dialogs/LogoutDialog.cs), and we are doing exactly the same (please see code in my post) but it is not working as expected. May be I am misunderstanding how the sign-in/sign-out works in Bot framework especially with Teams. I will keep looking and update the question. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think this works like you think it does. I don't think it's storing anything locally on the Teams client at all - I think it's storing a refresh token in the Bot Framework Service (which is why you need to configure the Connection details there). Bear in mind, this token is an SSO token - it's main use is for accessing other services on the user's behalf. It's not for "logging in" - Teams handles that for you. Maybe elaborate on what you're wanting to do with "log in" and "log out" in your scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to implement the bot authentication.

**1) Auth using SSO (Single-Sign-On)**

**Reference doc:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp

**You can refer this sample:** https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-sso

**2) Auth using OAuthCard**

**Reference doc link:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication-sso?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=eml

**You can refer this sample:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=userassigned%2Caadv2%2Ccsharp#prerequisites

Add authentication to a bot in Bot Framework SDK - Bot Service
Learn how to add user's authentication to your bot using Azure authentication.